# Change trigger to after insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, database-trigger

I don't know how to change the trigger to work as after insert

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_event_from_task BEFORE INSERT ON llx_projet_task
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO llx_actioncomm (priority, fulldayevent, location, label, fk_element, elementtype, fk_project, datep, datef, percentage, note)
    SELECT 0, 0, ' ', CONCAT(:new.ref, CONCAT(' - ', :new.label)), :new.id, 'project_task', :new.fk_project, :new.date_start, :new.date_end, :new.progress, :new.description
    FROM llx_projet_task;
END;
/
```

Comment: just replace after instead of before.. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_event_from_task AFTER INSERT ON llx_projet_task

Comment: Now say that table LLX_PROJET_TASK is mutating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the table from which trigger event happens (due to this mutating error occurred for more details [check here](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html) ). you already have value in terms of new.something so no need to fetch the value from the table. just use that value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_event_from_task AFTER INSERT ON llx_projet_task
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO llx_actioncomm (priority, fulldayevent, location, label, fk_element, elementtype, fk_project, datep, datef, percentage, note)
   VALUES( 0, 0, ' ', CONCAT(:new.ref, CONCAT(' - ', :new.label)), :new.id, 'project_task', :new.fk_project, :new.date_start, :new.date_end, :new.progress, :new.description);
END;
```